# Learning Angularjs 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am learning angularjs 2. I am following [this](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/index.html) git repo. Here I got below codes in *index.html*.

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

Why these codes used in *index.html* ? What are the necessitys of including these JavaScript files ?

Comment: This is documented in [Angular2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/)'s official documentation. I suggest you to go through them.

Comment: Thanks @abhishekkannojia for comment. I read Angular2 documentation , but could not get enough information.

Comment: You could have done a little bit more research before posting this question. Also, you could have put more efforts for choosing the right title for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Some provide the "polyfills/shims" to utilize modern JavaScript features that Angular2 requires, but a browser might not provide.  To clarify: a polyfill is code that provides functionality to a browser that might not be there natively (but is something a developer might expect to exist.  i.e. "I expect all of my clients to have browsers that support ES2015.").  Others provide additional functionality that Angular2 requires (zone.js provides an execution context that can be used with async tasks and Reflect.js provides reference introspection).

Take a look at your code in systemjs.config.js to see how `System.import('app')` is resolved...